# Hibernate Save Object without one column

Tags: hibernate, pojo, hbm

I have a table called test and It has columns like id, name, address. I have created POJO class(`User`) for all the three columns and same has been mapped with hbm configuration.

Here My questions is, How do I prevent one column while saving the User object in session (`session.save(User)`).

Let say I dont want to save my address field. How can I prevent. Are there any properties in HIbernate configuration or any modifier needs to be added in POJO?

Comment: don't you want that column included at all in the database? Or do you never want it to be updated after the initial insert? Or do you want it keep unchanged only for one specific call of save?

Answer (score 1):

- If you're using annotations config you could could do as follows,

  ```
  import javax.persistence.Transient;
   ....
  Class User{
    @Transient
    private String address;
    ....
  ```
- If you're using xml configuration just avoid creating a mapping to address propery in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. Unmapped properties are not saved by  hibernate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid a field from an entity to be persisted in DB one can use one of the two mechanisms:

[@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) - the JPA annotation marking a field as not persistable

transient keyword in java. Beware - using this keyword, will prevent the field to be used with any serialization mechanism from java. So, if the field must be serialized you'd better use just the @Transient annotation.