# How to update all properties of object except annotated @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I'm writing REST service. I have class Manager. It has property password. Property password annotated with @JsonIgnore.

```
public class Manager implements UserDetails {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;

private boolean accountNonExpired;
private boolean accountNonLocked;
private List<Authority> authorities;
private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
private boolean enabled;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phone;
@JsonIgnore
private String password;
...
```

When I get object from client it not consist password. How I can do
update all fields of the object except annotated @JsonIgnore using Hibernate?

```
public void update(Manager manager){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(manager);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @JsonIgnore annotation is applicable only for JSON serialization. If you want to avoid a column from saving in the table, then use @Transient annotation.

Hope this link will help - [Hibernate Save Object without one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106951/hibernate-save-object-without-one-column)